connecting the google drive to google colab
how to fix Failed to fetch error in connecting colab to drive by this code:
from google.colab import drive 
drive.mount('/content/food directory')

and this code
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

tried two code and they didn't work coming with the same error as before
and tried to connect through drive and my device didn't have the google colaboratory option
